# How to add html element to mxGraph

Tags: mxgraph

how I can add a html -element to my mxGraph object?
I imagine some thing like:

```html
const newDiv = document.createElement('div');
const newContent = document.createTextNode('The new div element!');
newDiv.appendChild(newContent);
drawIoUi.editor.graph.addMyNewHtmlElement(newDiv);
```

Thanks for help!
Frank

Comment: I also thought about using insertVertex(), but the content (text) is not shown at the mxGraph. drawIoUi.editor.graph.insertVertex(parent, null, newDiv, 40, 140, 300, 200);

Answer (score 1):

Examples are [here](https://jgraph.github.io/mxgraph/javascript/examples/htmllabel.html) and [here](https://jgraph.github.io/mxgraph/javascript/examples/ports.html). The list of all examples is [here](https://jgraph.github.io/mxgraph/javascript/index.html).

Answer (score 0):

```
const newDiv = document.createElement('div');
const parent = drawIoUi.editor.graph.getDefaultParent();
drawIoUi.editor.graph.getModel().beginUpdate();
try {
    const cell: any = drawIoUi.editor.graph.insertVertex(parent, null, newDiv, 40, 140, 300, 200);
    } finally {
        drawIoUi.editor.graph.getModel().endUpdate();
        drawIoUi.editor.graph.refresh();
        drawIoUi.editor.graph.container.focus();
    }
```